# Android Studio emulator freezing when attempting to change device orientation with emulator's buttons

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, freeze

I am using Android Studio's built-in emulator to emulate an AVD. Whenever I try to use the "Rotate left" or "Rotate right" buttons within the emulator window,

[image]

the emulation freezes up and becomes unresponsive to screen clicks, clicking device buttons, or visibly anything else.

I am wondering if this is a common issue maybe caused by allocated RAM to either the AVD or Android Studio and if anyone else has a solution to it. My system's resources are not low during emulation or general use of Android Studio either (I have 16GB RAM).

Below I have some more information on my current configuration of the AVD:

[image]

Please let me know if there are any logs you would like me to share that might help find the issue. I appreciate any help!

I have tried wiping the data of the AVD, creating it again, and rebooting several times, but the issue persists. Additionally, when I experience this freeze, I am unable to just close the emulator and reopen and launch the AVD again after since the emulator gets stuck on "Connecting to the Emulator", which forces me to wipe data and launch again - just for the issue to persist next time I try rotating.